# Extract values from a string using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to get values from the string using powershell.

This is the sample string

```
<Items>
<query t="default"><value>morning</value><en>morning</en></query>
<query t="default"><value>afternoon</value><en>afternoon</en></query>
<query t="default"><value>evening</value><en>evening</en></query>
</Items>
<SelectedValue></SelectedValue>
```

I want to get the result like

```
value: morning , en: morning
value: afternoon , en: afternoon
value: evening , en: evening
```

I tried the following regex but didn't work.

```
$pattern = '<query t="default">(.+?)<\/query>'
[regex]::Matches($testText, $pattern).Value
```

How can I get the `value` and `en` from the string.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing xml, you could simply cast your string to XmlDocument. Then you'll be able to easily access nodes. You only need to add root (can be any other name) for the string to be parsed.

```
$x=[xml]'<root>
<Items>
<query t="default"><value>morning</value><en>morning</en></query>
<query t="default"><value>afternoon</value><en>afternoon</en></query>
<query t="default"><value>evening</value><en>evening</en></query>
</Items>
<SelectedValue></SelectedValue></root>'

$x.root.items.query | select value,en
```

Result:

```
value     en       
-----     --       
morning   morning  
afternoon afternoon
evening   evening
```